# Macro not working in current version of CorelDRAW 2020

Tags: corel-draw

I'm creating Macro for UV Spot. I have recorded the macro in CorelDRAW 2020 and ran the macro not working (Inside the macro did not record). Then I recreated the same step in CorelDRAW X6 and ran it — it's working.

**Step to create my macro:**

Effect → adjust → brightness/contrast/intensity and set the value for Hue -180 and for contrast & intensity -100 which turns to black. Exported as GMS file and used in 2020 version. The macro is working in X6 but not in 2020.

**Macro code created in x6 and working fine** and not in 2020

[GMS file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jex_NB1awud-HcS7Q4ZvXWPiHOidx7kX/view?usp=sharing)

May I know the reason why it's not working in 2020?

Comment: Unfortunately I think we don't we have too many Corel draw users here. You might want to post this in some Corel draw focused forum as well.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Sounds more like a tech support question for Corel.  Tech support is off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I use Corel Draw, but never reused macros.

Some versions ago some menus were changed. One that I remember is Poser Clip, so there is a chance that the commands that you are using were too.

Your Macro does not sound too complicated. Imho it would be better to create a new one. :o(